# Type attribute video tag

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

I am using HTML5 player to play different formats of video and audio files. The only problem is I have to explicitly specify the type attribute of video tag for all different formats.
As I am planning to support many formats the list is growing very long.
Right now I am checking the file extension and using that as a conditional I am building if and else's to determine the type.
Is there a simple way to do this ?

Part of the code:

```
if($extension == "flv"){
        $type = "video/flv";
    }else if ($extension == "mp4") {
        $type = "video/mp4";
    }else if ($extension == "m3u8") {
        $type = "application/x-mpegURL";
    }else if ($extension == "m4v") {
        $type = "video/mp4";
    }else if ($extension == "mp3") {
        $type = "audio/mp3";
    }else if ($extension == "webm") {
        $type = "video/webm";
    }
```

Comment: Use an object instead?

Answer (score 2):

Use an object instead.

```
var types = { "flv" : "video/flv", "mp4" : "m3u8" /*add the others*/ }
$type = types[$extension];
```